# why the COUNTS_BY_COLOUR.COUNTS is invalid identifier in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

The following code gives an error when I specify the name of the columns(`select counts_by_colour.colour,counts_by_colour.counts` ), but if I say `select *` the code is executed. Why?

```
select counts_by_colour.colour,counts_by_colour.counts
from (select *
        from bricks
        CROSS JOIN (
        select count(*) as "total" from bricks) counts
        INNER JOIN (
         select colour, count(*) as "counts"
         from   bricks
         group by colour
       ) colours
       on bricks.colour=colours.colour) "counts_by_colour";
```

output:

```
ORA-00904: "COUNTS_BY_COLOUR"."COUNTS": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used a quoted identifier `"counts_by_colour"` and quoted identifiers a case sensitive.

In contrast, unquoted identifiers are implicitly converted to upper-case so `counts_by_colour` is converted to `COUNTS_BY_COLOUR`.

When you compare the two, `"counts_by_colour"` and `COUNTS_BY_COLOUR` are not the same identifiers as they have different cases so `COUNTS_BY_COLOUR` is not recognized.

You will find the same issue later as you have the quoted `"counts"` and the unquoted `counts`.

The solution is (for the most part) to **NEVER** use quoted identifiers.

---

More fundamentally, using the `colours_by_counts` alias not necessary (and may be syntactically invalid), as is using so many nested brackets, as you can refer to the table and sub-query aliases:

```sql
select colours.colour,
       colours.counts
from   bricks
       CROSS JOIN (select count(*) as total from bricks) counts
       INNER JOIN (
         select colour, count(*) as counts
         from   bricks
         group by colour
       ) colours
       on bricks.colour=colours.colour;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bricks (id, colour) AS
SELECT 1, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'blue' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLOUR | COUNTS |
> | --- | --- |
> | red | 3 |
> | red | 3 |
> | red | 3 |
> | green | 2 |
> | green | 2 |
> | blue | 1 |

If you do not want the duplicates then just use the aggregated sub-queries:

```sql
select *
from   (
         select colour, count(*) as counts
         from   bricks
         group by colour
       ) colours
       CROSS JOIN (select count(*) as total from bricks) counts;
```

Or, more simply, with analytic functions:

```sql
select colour,
       COUNT(*) AS counts,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS total
from   bricks
GROUP BY colour;
```

Which both output:

> | COLOUR | COUNTS | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | red | 3 | 6 |
> | green | 2 | 6 |
> | blue | 1 | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f53ea53adf2613cc62824af4313ad040)*